# Ef core Ownsone problem 'is sharing the table'

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use EF core : 2.26 and I have this data model:

```
public interface IManeuverableAsset 
    {
        OpenStateType? ManeuveredState { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IGeneratorManeuverableAsset : IManeuverableAsset
    { 
        DateRange GeneratorInstallation { get; set; }
        DateRange GeneratorRemoval { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManeuverableCabin : Entity<Guid>, IGeneratorManeuverableAsset
    {
        public Cabin Cabin { get; set; }
        public List<ManeuverableCell> Cells { get; set; } = new List<ManeuverableCell>();
        public DateRange GeneratorInstallation { get; set; }
        public DateRange GeneratorRemoval { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManeuverableCell : Entity<Guid>, IManeuverableAsset
    {
        public Cell Cell { get; set; }
        public List<ManeuverableCircuit> Circuits { get; set; } = new List<ManeuverableCircuit>();
        public OpenStateType? ManeuveredState { get; set; }

    }

    public class ManeuverableCircuit : Entity<Guid>, IGeneratorManeuverableAsset
    {
        public Circuit Circuit { get; set; }
        public OpenStateType? ManeuveredState { get; set; }
        public DateRange GeneratorInstallation { get; set; }
        public DateRange GeneratorRemoval { get; set; }
    }

   public class DateRange
    {
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    }
```

Config are like this:

```
   public class ManeuverableCabinConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ManeuverableCabin>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ManeuverableCabin> builder)
        {
            //builder.HasBaseType<ManeuverableAsset>();
            builder.OwnsOne(entity => entity.GeneratorInstallation);
            builder.OwnsOne(entity => entity.GeneratorRemoval);
            builder.ToTable(nameof(ManeuverableCabin) + "s");
        }
    }

    public class ManeuverableCellConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ManeuverableCell>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ManeuverableCell> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(nameof(ManeuverableCell) + "s");
        }
    }

   public class ManeuverableCircuitConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ManeuverableCircuit>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ManeuverableCircuit> builder)
        {        
            builder.OwnsOne(entity => entity.GeneratorInstallation);
            builder.OwnsOne(entity => entity.GeneratorRemoval);
            builder.ToTable(nameof(ManeuverableCircuit) + "s");

        }
    }
```

When I save just a ManeuverableCabin (without cells/circuits), it works fine, but, as soon as I have a ManeuvrableCircuit without value inside my DateRange, I have this error:

> The entity of type 'ManeuverableCabin' is sharing the table
>   'ManeuverableCabin' with entities of type
>   'ManeuverableCabin.GeneratorInstallation#DateRange', but there is no
>   entity of this type with the same key value that has been marked as
>   'Added'. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key
>   values.'

My date range are never null, at best they are just default empty instances.
Here is how i save data:

```
 public async Task SaveAsync(TEntity aggregate)
    {
        var existingAggregate = await _context.FindAsync<TEntity>(aggregate.Id);

        if (existingAggregate == null)
            await _context.AddAsync(aggregate).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

When i put a breakpoint on await _context.AddAsync(aggregate).ConfigureAwait(false);
My aggregate looks like this:
[image]

But when I step over and get to the SaveChangesAsync, my objects changes:
[image]
Seeing different post, I am pretty sure the problem is that the object becomes null but I have no idea why...
Of course if I have value in my daterange, everything is fine...

Any idea on this?
Sorry for long post

Thanks!

Comment: Please include `DateRange` class and the exact EF Core version.

Comment: @IvanStoev done, thanks for telling me :) I use 2.26

Comment: Make sure you are not *sharing* `DateRange` object *instances* between entities, e.g. like value objects - this is [not supported by EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings)

Comment: @IvanStoev you are my savior... Automapper uses the same instance... I just tested with new instances all the time at t worked... Can you put it as answer so i can accept it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ivan Stoev said, the object was shared due to nullsubstitute in auto mapper which was using the same instance..